# Vuetify - Unknown custom element problem with any component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I've trying to solve this problem for the last 2 hours and can't find the solution. I created a new project with `Vue cli` and installed `Vuetify` with npm.

My files are like this

**App.vue**

```js
    <template>
    <v-app id="app">
       <HelloWorld/>
      </v-app>
    </template>

    <script>
    import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue';

    export default {
      name: 'App',
      components: {
        HelloWorld
      },

      data: () => ({
        //
      }),
    };
    </script>
```

**main.js**

```js
    import Vue from 'vue'
    import Vuetify from './plugins/vuetify';
    import App from './App.vue'

    Vue.config.productionTip = false

    Vue.use(Vuetify); 

    new Vue({
      render: h => h(App)
    }).$mount('#app')
```

**HelloWorld.vue**

```js
    <template>
       <v-tabs>
        <v-tab>Item One</v-tab>
        <v-tab>Item Two</v-tab>
        <v-tab>Item Three</v-tab>
      </v-tabs>
    </template>

    <script>
      export default {
        name: 'HelloWorld',
      }
    </script>
```

The error I get is:

> **[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element:  - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide
>   the "name" option.
>
> found in
>
> --->  at components/HelloWorld.vue
>           at App.vue
>            **

I also tried to use any component directly in the vue.app and get the same problem. Before posting here I lookup to at least 10 different posts, and I read that I should call vuetify before the new Vue but that didn't solve the problem. I dont know if there is something missing or I just cant see the problem.

Thanks for reading my post

Comment: Finally made it work.

The problem was that it wasn't loading the dependencies. I used vue create helloworld then vue add vuetify. This generated two levels of node_modules, the first one with all the dependencies, and the second one inside the src folder with only the vuetify dependencies. Had to install everything in it's correct place one by one. Then got a problem with styles, which I solved adding "import "vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css";" in my plugins/vuetify.js file. Hope this helps someone someday.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the problem is with `<v-tabs>`. I'm not very familiar with vuetify. Shouldn't this component be imported and registered (like any other component would be?).

**EDIT**

Oh I think you need to pass `Vuetify`

```js
new Vue({
  Vuetify,
}).$mount('#app')
```

They have a getting started doc here:

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/quick-start

Try to setup your project in the same way.

Comment: I passed Vuetify, however I'm still getting the same problems. I'm starting to think that the problem might be in other place

Answer (score 0):

try to follow the quick start documentation in Vuetify.

```
import vuetify from '@/plugins/vuetify'

new Vue({
  vuetify,
}).$mount('#app')
```

your import path is **'@/plugins/vuetify'** instead of **'./plugins/vuetify'**
and add the vuetify into your Vue({   }).$mount('#app') as shown above.

Hope it help

Comment: Tried doing this steps, and also following the quick start doc and still having the same problem :c

Comment: Try to put your code in codesandbox, easier for us to help u to debug